# Tiddlywiki5, formatting filter results

Tags: tiddlywiki

Given a filter like `[tag[introduction]]`, how can I modify the formatting of the displayed results, for example like adding white-spaces between each one, or setting up a bullet list out of them?

[Here](http://tiddlywiki.com/static/Introduction%2520to%2520Filters.html) for more info about TiddlyWiki filters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're much more likely to get a quick answer on the [google groups](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tiddlywiki).

A [filter](http://tiddlywiki.com/#Filters) by itself does not render anything, widgets do... and subsequently macros.

So, simply put, your desired item-format inside the [list widget](http://tiddlywiki.com/#ListWidget) that renders it:

```
<$list filter="[tag[TableOfContents]]">
<$link to=<<currentTiddler>>><$view field=title/></$link>&nbsp;
</$list>
```

**Tip:** Try any of this creating a test tiddler directly on http://tiddlywiki.com.

This renders a link to each iterated item on the list showing its title. Notice the `&nbsp;` at the end to provide for simple spacing.

When the inner text of a list widget starts with an empty line, TiddlyWiki understands your code as wanting to have block-level paragraph elements, rather than an inline list.

```
<$list filter="[tag[TableOfContents]]">

<$link to=<<currentTiddler>>><$view field=title/></$link>
</$list>
```

However, I sometimes prefer using a nice » `&raquo;` and a trailing newline via `<br>`...

```
<$list filter="[tag[TableOfContents]]">
&raquo; <$link to=<<currentTiddler>>><$view field=title/></$link><br>
</$list>
```

Alternatively you can use a template tiddler defining the item template, i.e.

```
<$list filter="[tag[GettingStarted]]" template="$:/.sagado/templates/my-list"/>
```

With a [standard template](http://tiddlywiki.com/#%24%3A%2Fcore%2Fui%2FListItemTemplate) ...

```
<$list filter="[tag[TableOfContents]]" template="$:/core/ui/ListItemTemplate"/>
```

This is perhaps the cleanest approach as it allows you to reuse that template elsewhere.

Alternatively, use the [list-links](http://tiddlywiki.com/#ListMacro) macro to output simple link lists, e.g.:

```
<<list-links filter:"[tag[TableOfContents]]">>
```

**Note:** Notice the syntax differences between a macro and a widget call, i.e. double angle brakets and colons for (optionally named) parameters, rather than attrib="value".

You can easily wrap this in your [custom css class](http://tiddlywiki.com/#Using%20Stylesheets), e.g.

```
@@.my-class
<<list-links filter:"[tag[TableOfContents]]">>
@@
```

To properly render tables or definition lists, use html tags outside and inside...

```
<dl>
<$list filter="[has[url]]">
<dt><$link to=<<currentTiddler>>><$view field=title/></$link></dt>
<dd>{{!!url}}</dd>
</$list>
</dl>
```

Here's an a bit more elaborate table syntax using a macro to generate a link...

```
\define link(url) [ext[>>|$url$]]
<table>
<tr><th>Title</th><th>Link</th></tr>
<$list filter="[has[url]]">
<tr>
<td><$link to=<<currentTiddler>>><$view field=title/></$link></td>
<td><$macrocall $name=link url={{!!url}}></td>
</tr>
</$list>
</table>
```

For more, see...

http://tb5.tiddlyspot.com/#How%20to%20style%20lists

Comment: Is it possible to make this behave differently on certain list iterations, e.g. to produce output formatted like `[[Foo]], [[Bar]] and [[Baz]]`? Or do I have to drop into Javascript macros for that?

Comment: By the way, this may have changed recently, but it seems that the explicit `&nbsp;` is not needed in the first approach, at least when the `filter` is a simple title list that comes from a variable.